# How to read host file content of Azure DevOps Agent?

Tags: azure-devops

I have Agent VM. I would like to read and display value of host file so that I can troubleshoot network issues related to CI/CD.

Could it done with simple script on pipeline? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
- pwsh: | 
    gc C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | write-host
```

or

```
- bash: | 
    cat C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```